# Why does zsh alias not evaluate properly the nested command?

Tags: docker, zsh

In my ~/.zshrc i set up an alias

```sh
alias dkill="docker kill $(docker ps -q)"
```

but it does not actually run like the command itself does.

For some reason it tries to execute container names as commands instead of passing them to the `docker kill` command.

```sh
Error response from daemon: Cannot kill container: 3f1xxxxx0c4: No such container: 3f1xxxxx0c4
zsh: command not found: 0aexxxxxx913
zsh: command not found: 46acxxxx75cd
zsh: command not found: 20f9xxxxx9c1
zsh: command not found: 63edxxxxc085
zsh: command not found: 6328xxxxfe4d
```

How should i redefine the alias to kill containers properly

Comment: The double quotes cause the command substitution to be evaluated when you *define* the alias. Generally, functions are superior to aliases in every way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As @triplee says, the command is evaluated as soon as you define the alias (when you open you zsh session, container might not exist).

In your `.zshrc` use a function instead:

```
function dkill { docker kill $(docker ps -q) }
```

Or use single quotes:

```
alias dkill='docker kill $(docker ps -q)'
```